# Transform code into flexbox.. align two divs

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a code which produces this but I would like to use Flexbox instead as my current code is quite messy. How would I do that?

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container2 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 48%;
  background: #fff;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  background: #fff;
}

.red {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
    <button class="red">
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19e8nmr3/

Comment: So are you wanting the 2 divs to be 50% 50%? Or keep them at 40% 48%?

Comment: I don't see any attempt here to use flex-box. Why not find a tutorial on how it works and go from there?

Comment: I would like the two divs in the middle to have a width of 50%

Comment: Why bother using flexbox for such a simple task?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/19e8nmr3/1/ you don't really need flexbox here, but as wanted. I stripped out the unnecessary container2 element

Comment: hello @user3528269 please could i have the two div elements an equal 50 width

Comment: I'm not using flexbox usually but this seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/19e8nmr3/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `p` elements in one parent element and use `flex: 1`.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.wrap p,
button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <button class="red">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, i tried this but what if i need different content in the left and right div

Comment: Can you show in fiddle what you mean?

Comment: how would i add more text inside the wrap? like if I wanted different text after hello

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/19e8nmr3/3/ or this https://jsfiddle.net/19e8nmr3/5/?